# Indentation incorrect in line with `if:` or `unless:` as options, not directives

Tags: indentation, ruby-mode

In some of my ruby files, mostly Rails Model files, I often encounter lines such as:

```
  validates :thing_id, presence: { message: '^Choose a Thing' },
    on: :create, 
    unless: Proc.new { |obj| ... some condition ... }
```

Where the `unless:` is treated like the `unless` directive, and so throws the indentation off for the rest of the file. This also happens with an `if:` option.

Has anyone found a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably using the legacy indentation code, enabled with `(setq ruby-use-smie nil)`.

Set that variable to `t` (its default), restart Emacs, and the problem will disappear.